# Backbone Marionette code improvement 2

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How could this code be improved and have fewer repeated lines?

```
vent.on("createAccountLayout:rendered", function() {
    logger.info('createAccountLayout:rendered => CreateAccountLayoutController');
    showRegion(['phoneNumberRegion', 'keyboardRegion', 'nextRegion', 'quitRegion']);

    vent.trigger('createAccountLayout:setToNumericKeyboard');
});

vent.on('createAccountPhoneNumberView:nextStep', function() {
    closeRegion(['phoneNumberRegion', 'keyboardRegion', 'nextRegion']);
    showRegion(['nameRegion', 'keyboardRegion', 'nextRegion']);

    vent.trigger('createAccountLayout:setToAlphaNumericKeyboard');
    vent.trigger('createAccountLayout:disableNextButton');
});
```

Comment: If the code isn't that repetitive or that many, I suggest you leave it be. This is too little for a generic routine to be created.

Comment: Noted. Though while coding this module, I realized that there's going to be more of those. So I want to simplify this before things gets out of hand.

Comment: As far as I remember, I have answered a question of yours that holds the same pattern. You can apply a similar approach.

Answer (score 2):

Answerifying what Joseph the Dreamer commented on,

there is really not enough code to build a general routine out of, the code is fine as is. Though ideally you could add comments.